# Using Foursquare API with python

Tags: python, pandas, foursquare

How do i extract the list of hospitals in each neighborhood in a city using foursquare API? and putting it into a data frame.

This is what i am trying to achieve as a DataFrame:

```
    Neighborhood  No. of hospitals
0  Neighborhood1                 5
1  Neighborhood2                 1
2  Neighborhood3                 3
3  Neighborhood4                 4
4  Neighborhood5                 5
```

I am trying out a code from a previous tutorial to achieve this, I expected the error but i don't know where to start.

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=500):

venues_list=[]
for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
    print(name)
        
    # create the API request URL
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={}&query=supermarket,{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
        CLIENT_ID, 
        CLIENT_SECRET, 
        VERSION, 
        lat, 
        lng, 
        radius, 
        LIMIT)
        
    # make the GET request
    results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']
    
    # return only relevant information for each nearby venue
    venues_list.append([(
        name, 
        lat, 
        lng, 
        v['venue']['name'], 
        v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
        v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
        v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
nearby_venues.columns = ['Neighborhood', 
              'Neighborhood Latitude', 
              'Neighborhood Longitude', 
              'Venue', 
              'Venue Latitude', 
              'Venue Longitude', 
              'Venue Category']

return(nearby_venues)
```

Next cell:

```
Toronto_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=Toronto_df['Neighborhood'],
                               latitudes=Toronto_df['Latitude'],
                               longitudes=Toronto_df['Longitude']
                              )
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do value counts, then separate out any column and rename it.

```
df = Toronto_venues.groupby('Neighborhood').count()  # Get the counts
df = pd.DataFrame(df['Venue']) # Convert the counts to a dataframe
df.rename(columns={'Venue': 'No. of Hospitals'}, inplace=True)
```

At this point you will have a dataframe, but the first column which is your hospital names, is the index. If you want to pull it out into a column, then use this code as well:

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: df = Toronto_venues.groupby('Neighborhood').count()  # Get the counts
df = pd.DataFrame(Toronto_venues['Venue']) # Convert the counts to a dataframe
df = df.columns = ['No. of Hospitals']  # rename the column


This one gives this error: 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: @jaiswalfelipe, I adjusted the code. I had an error in line two and I adjusted how the renaming of the column was done. It is working for me, so hopefully it will for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response,

```
Toronto_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=Toronto_df['Neighborhood'],
                               latitudes=Toronto_df['Latitude'],
                               longitudes=Toronto_df['Longitude']
                              )
```

But this cell gives back this error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-03f6027f84a2> in <module>()
      1 Toronto_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=Toronto_df['Neighborhood'],
      2                                latitudes=Toronto_df['Latitude'],
----> 3                                longitudes=Toronto_df['Longitude']
      4                               )

<ipython-input-13-0c3ca691c166> in getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius)
     16 
     17         # make the GET request
---> 18         results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']
     19 
     20         # return only relevant information for each nearby venue

KeyError: 'groups'
```